# Issue about library Hi-CLASS and Python3.9 (both built from macOS Intel API) : segfault on a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, openmp, intel, intel-oneapi

have a problem with a unique python3.9 interpreter on 2 codes :

the first one works fine and not the second one.

I have installed on MacOS 14.0 all the Intel oneapi framework.

Then, I have compiled the library " hi_classy.cpython-39-darwin.so" from Hi-CLASS Boltzmann code ( https://miguelzuma.github.io/hi_class_public/ )

With "-qopenmp" flag for the compilation, it depends on :

`# otool -L hi_classy.cpython-39-darwin.so`
`hi_classy.cpython-39-darwin.so:`
`@rpath/libomp.dylib (compatibility version 5, current version 5.)`
`@rpath/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1. current version 1.)`
`/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1. current version 1311)`

As you can see, there is a " libomp.dylib " dependance.

You can also see it in attachment.

For the original library, I have the following dependances :

`# otool -L hi_classy.cpython-39-darwin.so_SAVE_ORIGINAL`
`hi_classy.cpython-39-darwin.so_SAVE_ORIGINAL:`
`@rpath/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)`
`/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.)`

For most of all my python scripts, there is no problem with that dependance but with a script, I have always a segmentation fault whereas  if I take the original version (no "-qopenmp" flag, everythig works fine.

So, I am looking for someone that can help me to circumdent this issue.

The goal is to get a uique libray that makes work the 2 codes.

I tried to build a unique hi-classy library but I have still get this segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

you may like to try to set stacksize environmental parameters
Examples

```
setenv OMP_STACKSIZE 2000500B 
setenv OMP_STACKSIZE "3000 k " 
setenv OMP_STACKSIZE 10M 
setenv OMP_STACKSIZE " 10 M " 
setenv OMP_STACKSIZE "20 m " 
setenv OMP_STACKSIZE " 1G" 
setenv OMP_STACKSIZE 20000
```

To show current evnironmental settings:

```
export OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=true
 ulimit -a
```

To set:

```
export OMP_STACKSIZE=16M
```

for MacOS:

```
  ulimit -s hard
```

for non Mac OS

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

References:

https://depts.washington.edu/clawpack/sampledocs/v570_docs/v5.3.0/openmp.html
[https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse54.html#:~:text=The%20OMP_STACKSIZE%20environment%20variable%20controls,stack%20for%20an%20initial%20thread](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse54.html#:%7E:text=The%20OMP_STACKSIZE%20environment%20variable%20controls,stack%20for%20an%20initial%20thread).